# Multiple submit button getting null value in controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, submit

Im using mvc4  and im getting JSON from http://api.feedzilla.com/v1/categories.json

My model has the following code

```
public class catagorygroup
    {

        public List<CatagoryModel> catagoryModel { get; set; } 

    }

    public class CatagoryModel
    {

        public int category_id { get; set; }
        public string english_category_name { get; set; }
    }
```

my view is like this

```
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.catagoryModel.Count; i++)
        {
            using (Html.BeginForm("News", "Catagory"))
            {

            <li> <input type="submit"   name="w8-red" class="w8-button red"  value= @Model.catagoryModel[i].english_category_name   /> </li>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.catagoryModel[i].category_id);
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.catagoryModel[i].english_category_name); 

        <br/><br/>
            }
            }
```

and my view is like this

[image]

If i click the **First button** Sports Button Im getting the "Name,Id " value like this

[image]

**but if i click any button other than the first button im getting something like this [Null values]**
[image]

What went wrong in my code

Comment: u are making multiple forms in a single page. !!

Comment: Yes .and each buttons like "Sports,Arts,Blog,etc" are submit buttons having its own Form

Comment: @AshokDamani   But it will post the entire Model right , I need to get only the "category_id,english_category_name" of the selected button , For example if i click "Sports= i will get some id and name " similarly if i click "Art= it should give only the art id and name " got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this, it may works

```
@Html.ActionLink(model.catagoryModel[i].english_category_name,
             "News",
             new { @Model.catagoryModel[i].english_category_name,
                   @Model.catagoryModel[i].category_id },
             new { @class = "w8-button red" });
```

Answer (score 1):

That looks like it may be better suited as an anchor tag.

```
@Html.ActionLink(model.catagoryModel[i].english_category_name,
                 "News",
                 "Catagory",
                 new { @Model.catagoryModel[i].english_category_name,
                       @Model.catagoryModel[i].category_id },
                 new { @class = "w8-button red" });
```

See: [`LinkExtensions.ActionLink`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink.aspx)

Sample:

```
//HomeController.cs

public class HomeController : Controller
{
     public ActionResult Index()
     {
         return View();
     }

    public ActionResult DoWork(SomeDTO dto)
    {
        return View("Index");
    }
}

public class SomeDTO
{
    public int SomeId { get; set; }
    public string SomeData { get; set; }
}

//Index.cshtml

@Html.ActionLink("Home", "DoWork", new { SomeId = 1, SomeData = "World" })

//RouteConfig.cs

public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home",
                            action = "Index",
                            id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: NO im getting error  /Category/News?english_category_name=Blogs&category_id=21 and HTTP 404 error how can i get those values in controller

Comment: Remove the `HttpPost` attribute on the `News` method.

Comment: No , Im getting the value in the URL like this Category/News?english_category_name=Blogs&category_id=21 but stil HTTP 404 error

Comment: I edited in a sample for you. However, you might have some routing issues if an action link is not working.

Comment: @Romoku. Thanks for your code . And can you kindly help me how to resolve routing problem

Comment: Ensure that the ActionLink is using the proper Action/Controller and make sure you have the default route in the RouteConfig.cs. See my edit.

Comment: @Romoku , i have some thing like this routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Catagory", action = "Catagory", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );